# How to build "edit" button in JSF and switch between h:outputText and h:inputText

Tags: jsf, edit, conditional-rendering

How can I create an "edit" button so that when the button is clicked it will change the `h:outputText` to `h:inputText`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make use of the `rendered` attribute:

```html
<h:outputText value="#{bean.entity.property}" rendered="#{not bean.editmode}" />
<h:inputText value="#{bean.entity.property}" rendered="#{bean.editmode}" />
...
<h:commandButton value="Edit" action="#{bean.edit}" rendered="#{not bean.editmode}" />
<h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{bean.save}" rendered="#{bean.editmode}" />
```

With this in a view scoped bean:

```java
private boolean editmode;

public void edit() {
    editmode = true;
}

public void save() {
    entityService.save(entity);
    editmode = false;
}

public boolean isEditmode() {
    return editmode;
}

// ...
```

Note that the bean being view scoped is important for the reason mentioned in point 5 of this answer: [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked).

---

Alternatively, you can use the `disabled` attribute on input component in combination with a shot of CSS which basically makes it look like an output component (by removing the border).

```html
<h:inputText value="#{bean.entity.property}" disabled="#{not bean.editmode}" />
...
<h:commandButton value="Edit" action="#{bean.edit}" rendered="#{not bean.editmode}" />
<h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{bean.save}" rendered="#{bean.editmode}" />
```

with e.g.

```
input[disabled] {
    border: 0;
}
```

Also here, the bean must be view scoped. See also [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)